# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input : at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, local-storage

it throws error when I try to parse localStorage['highscores"]

```
if (localStorage["highscores"] == undefined) {
    localStorage["highscores"] = [];
}
var highscores = JSON.parse(localStorage["highscores"]) || [];
```

I have not defined localStorage['highscores"] so I try to check it and if it is undefined define it, bcs if it is full I want to save it's information in localStorage['highscores"] and add more information too.

any ideas?

Comment: it should be `if (typeof localStorage["highscores"] == 'undefined') {`

Comment: same error expected

Comment: @JaydeepChauhan That should not make a difference in 99.9% of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Local Storage may only hold strings. When you set non-strings to it, it'll be coerced to a string.

When arrays are converted to strings, `.join(',')` is called on the string. The empty array will be converted into the empty string:

```js
console.log(String([]) === '');
```

Which is not JSON-parseable.

Save the JSON-stringified version of the empty array instead.

```
if (localStorage.highscores === undefined) {
    localStorage.highscores = '[]';
}
```

or

```
if (localStorage.highscores === undefined) {
    localStorage.highscores = JSON.stringify([]);
}
```

When in doubt, always use `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` when transferring to and from Local Storage.

Comment: You might have already put some invalid JSON into local storage. Try clearing your local storage first.

Comment: It's empty 
error appeared when I cleared localstorage

Comment: Works just fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/e5aq79Lr/ If it's not working for you, you must have other code messing with storage that isn't in the question - or you didn't copy the code from the answer correctly